# There is an error on the return ( and I cannot understand why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, redux, state

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class MyStories extends React.Component {


  addFavorite = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      bgcolor: "blue"
    })
  }


  render () {
  const { stories }  = this.props;
    const { storyBriefs }  = this.props.stories.length > 0 ?

          stories.map(t => (<div className="menu-inner-container"><p key={t.id}><Link to={`/stories/${t.id}`}>{t.attributes.title}</Link>
           <div className="addFavoriteCss"
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor}}
            onClick={this.addFavorite}> Favorite</div>
        </p></div>))

//refactor - create a button that will allow for us to mark which our favorites are

  return (
    { this.props.storyBriefs }
   );
  }

 }
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    stories: state.myStories
  }
 }


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyStories)
```

getting this error

./src/components/MyStories.js
  Line 26:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ":"

```
    return (
      ^
   { this.props.storyBriefs }
  );
 }
```

---

I converted a functional component to a class component so that I could manipulate the state in order to change the color of the favorite button -- (I cannot use hooks or redux for the button function) Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `{ this.props.storyBriefs }` is not valid object syntax - and is it even a valid prop? perhaps you wanted just `return ( { storyBriefs } )`

Comment: I had just {storyBriefs} and getting same error. So I changed that back

Comment: well, use `return ( { storyBriefs: storyBriefs  } )` - perhaps your environment doesn't understand object shorthand

Comment: but still getting the same error

Comment: even with `return ( { storyBriefs: storyBriefs } )`? I doubt it's the SAME error

Comment: The `return` statement is invalid there. You need to provide an expression for the case where `this.props.stories.length > 0 ` is `false`. The syntax of the conditional operator is `condition ? if-true : if-false`. Both `if-true` and `if-false` need to be expressions. `{ this.props.storyBriefs }` is still an issue but it's not what the error is about.

Comment: yeah, getting the same error

Comment: @FelixKling can you tell me how to do that? I am going blank

Comment: Here is a simpler example of how to use the conditional operator: `var max = x > y ? x : y`. The error clearly tells you that the parser expects to see a colon (`:`) after the first branch of the conditional operator.

Comment: @FelixKling, also the storyBriefs is the child and stories (myStories) is the parent. After changing over from functional component to the class component, I may have not converted correctly

Comment: Btw, `const { storyBriefs }  = ... ? stories.map(...)` is also wrong because an array does not have a `storyBriefs` property.

Comment: I think all you need is maybe `return this.prop.stories.map(....)`. Unless you want to render a message in case `stories` is empty I don't see a reason to use the conditional operator.

Comment: @FelixKling, added this.props.stories.map (That is one way I had before as well) I have done so much refactoring that I have lost some and can't seem to get errors straight now. Still have an error, but I know that part is correct that you suggestt. I am confused about the storyBriefs, as it is child component and not sure how to get the return to work properly

Comment: got this error on the developer tools .     backend.js:6 ./src/components/MyStories.js
  Line 16:  'stories' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: If you destructure stories with ```const { stories } = this.props```, then you don't need to type out ```this.props.stories```, you can just use ```stories``` instead. If you want to get rid of that error, either just use ```stories``` instead of ```this.props.stories``` or remove the ```const {stories} = this.props``` line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the ternary operator by adding `:`

```
 const storyBriefs  = this.props.stories.length > 0 ?

          stories.map(t => (<div className="menu-inner-container"><p key={t.id}><Link to={`/stories/${t.id}`}>{t.attributes.title}</Link>
           <div className="addFavoriteCss"
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor}}
            onClick={this.addFavorite}> Favorite</div>
        </p></div>))

: [] // you need something here after the ':', an empty array could be useful in this case

 return storyBriefs
```

or you could shorten it to

```
 return stories.map(t => (<div className="menu-inner-container"><p key={t.id}><Link to={`/stories/${t.id}`}>{t.attributes.title}</Link>
           <div className="addFavoriteCss"
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor}}
            onClick={this.addFavorite}> Favorite</div>
        </p></div>))
```

Comment: While this will solve the error in the OPs question, the code still won't work because arrays don't have a `storyBriefs` property. Also if using an empty array is really the desired result, then there is no need to use the conditional operator at all. They can just do `const result = stories.map(...)` and get the same result. Mapping over an empty array will return an empty array.

Comment: I did have : null after the` </p></div>))`

Answer (score 0):

As Jaromanda X said { this.props.storyBriefs } isn't valid. you need to provide the key value pair unless the variable doesn't have dot notation then you can define the object like that

Comment: now that i read your comment to Jaromanda comment maybe it is the parenthesis around the object which are giving the problems

Answer (score 0):

This was the final code and it works,

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class MyStories extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      button: false
    };
    this.addFavorite = this.addFavorite.bind(this);
  }

  addFavorite = id => {
    this.setState({
      button: id
    });
  };

  render() {
    return this.props.stories.map(t => (
      <div className="menu-inner-container">
        <p key={t.id}>
          <Link to={`/stories/${t.id}`}>{t.attributes.title}</Link>
          <button
            key={t.id}
            className={this.state.button===t.id ? "buttonTrue" : "buttonFalse"}
            onClick={() => this.addFavorite(t.id)}
          >
            Favorites
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

//refactor - create a button that will allow for us to mark which our favorites are
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    stories: state.myStories
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyStories);
```